# How to get last x records from a list with Lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, c#-4.0

I have as List of strings with where i remove each duplicates, now I want to filter it even more to get the last 5 records. How can I do this?

What I got so far

```
 List<string> query = otherlist.Distinct().Select(a => a).ToList();
```

Comment: Why the `Select(a => a)`? It doesn't do anything...

Comment: that was my "dummy"  to put the last x records filter

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not need the `.Select(a => a)`. Thats redundant.

You can get the last 5 records, by skipping over the rest like

```
List<string> query = otherlist.Distinct().ToList();
List<string> lastFive = query.Skip(query.Count-5).ToList();
```

Comment: Skip() has a better performance than Reverse() then Take(), obviously.

Comment: @Danny: Not as much as you'd think: the `ToList()` call will be just as expensive as my first `Reverse()` (traverse the whole list once), and after the `Take(5)` it's just reversing five elements which is peanuts. Also, my way doesn't create an intermediate list.

Comment: @tzaman - " my way doesn't create an intermediate list" - yes it does; two of them, in fact. How do you think `Reverse` operates? (well, strictly speaking it creates an `T[]` array, courtesy of `Buffer<T>` - but same difference)

Comment: @Marc - huh. Of course; silly of me. Still, a bit of timing I just did now seems to have indicate my solution running faster than this one (or yours). Take a look? http://pastebin.com/a65UMZfP

Answer (score 5):

**edit** to cater for non-list inputs, now handles `IEnumerable<T>` and *checks* if this is an `IList<T>`; if not it buffers it via `ToList()`, which helps ensure we only read the data **once** (rather than `.Count()` and `.Skip()` which may read the data multiple times).

Since this is a list, I'd be inclined to write an extension method that uses that to the full:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(
           this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
    {
        IList<T> list = (source as IList<T>) ?? source.ToList();
        count = Math.Min(count, list.Count);
        for (int i = list.Count - count; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            yield return list[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Absolutely. Given you know it's a list, this is a simple and easily the most efficient approach.

Comment: Except it won't be a list when it comes out of the `Distinct()` call; the `ToList()` only needs to happen once at the end.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
var lastFive = list.Reverse().Take(5).Reverse();
```

edit: here's the whole thing -

```
var lastFiveDistinct = otherlist.Distinct()
                                .Reverse()
                                .Take(5)
                                .Reverse()
                                .ToList();
```

Also note that you shouldn't call it `query` if you've got a `ToList()` call at the end, because then it's *not* a query anymore, it's been evaluated and turned into a list. If you only need it to iterate over, you can omit the `ToList()` call and leave it as an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I'd venture that it would be cheaper to count the elements then use Skip and Take. Reversing an IEnumerable can't be cheap.

Comment: It's the same asymptotic complexity either way, but you're right that skip/take is probably faster.

Comment: Actually, I'll amend my earlier statement - I don't think there will be a noticeable performance difference. See my comment on Jens' answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count=list.Count();
var last5=list.Skip(count-5);
```

EDIT:

I missed that the data is List<T> . This approach would be better for IEnumerable<T>